# Where will be the message after all attempts to deliver at endpoint in mule rollback exception strategy?

Tags: exception, mule, rollback

where message will go in mule rollback exception after all attempts are done to deliver at outbound endpoint. Whether message will be in inbound endpoint(queue) ?

Answer (score 0):

When all attempts are performed, the **redelivery exhausted** area is executed. In that area is where you implement the logic for when the **Max redelivery attempts** were reached. It is up to you to define what needs to be done with the message when that situation occurs. Check the [following](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/rollback-exception-strategy) mule page for more info.

Hope it helps.